# Can we get properties using Expression from Properties File

Tags: java, spring

Can we get a property from properties file using some expression. e.g

If I have properties in file like this

```
user/a/b=active
user/a/c=active
user/a/d=active
```

Now How can I get all properties which are active. Also Can I get all active using `user/a/*` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java.util.Properties class has stringPropertyNames() method

you can use the method to iterate all the names and check name and value

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

// add some properties
prop.put("user/a/b", "active");
prop.put("user/a/c", "active");
prop.put("user/a/d", "active");

// save the Property names in the set
Set<String> set = prop.stringPropertyNames();
for (String name: set) {
    if (name.startsWIth("user/a/")) {
        //check value and do something
    }
}
```